# Difference between 74HC138N and 74AC138N

Tags: integrated-circuit

What is the difference between 74HC138N and 74AC138, since the last one is way more expensive than the HC version? Can HC be used instead of AC version to drive [TLC5490](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf) Led Driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HC** - high speed CMOS

**AC** - Advanced CMOS.

They are both CMOS construction, function wise they are the same. The difference is basically speed. So yes you can use the HC version. Speed is not an issue for driving LEDs. They are both fast.

Comment: As an aside, OP is not driving LEDs directly, but controlling a TLC5940, so speed might still be a concern, as opposed to driving LEDs directly - not a concern unless OP is attempting the full 30 MHz data transfer rate the TLC5940 driver supports.

Comment: 74AC series requires extra attention when it comes to decoupling due to its speed.